# How to access a JSON request body of a POST request in Slim rest api?

Tags: json, rest, slim

i am trying to sent http post with json body and don't know  how to handle with slim i tried diffrent soluctions found in stackoverflow but it showing error 500
i tryed
 
`$app->post('/login', function () use ($app) {
    $json = $app->request->getBody();
    $data = json_decode($json, true); 
});` 

but it returning "Slim Application Error
A website error has occurred. Sorry for the temporary inconvenience."

Comment: 500, there is something of your conf of slim. There is defined '/login' as post ?, or get?, exists?...

Comment: i don't under stand sir

Answer (score 0):

You only need to get the parsed request body from Slim
Slim take care of  decoding and sent it back to you as PHP array          You also will add Request and Response in your route function
You code will be like that

```
$app->post('/login', function ($request,$response){
    $Arr = $request->getParsedBody();
    //you did not need to re decode the body using this way     
    //$data = json_decode($json, true); 
});
```

Comment: $app->post('/login', function ($request, $response, $args) {
  $data = $request->getParsedBody();
  
 });

Comment: Question looks like slim v2, but your answer shows code from v3